# How to change page view dots position in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I searched for this but cannot find any useful solution for me. How can I change my page view dots position by Y?

Now I have them on the bottom of my ViewController. How can make them +200 from the bottom?

I set up my dots here:

```
private func setupPageControl() {
    let appearance = UIPageControl.appearance()
    appearance.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    appearance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
}
```

but when I've tried to:

```
appearance.layer.position.y = 200
```

it doesn't make a sense. All my controller code is here, if you want: http://pastebin.com/1hLRFPsR

Comment: What was `appearance.layer.position.y = 200` result?

Comment: @Mayerz nothing. It did not change the position at all

Answer (score 5):

You need to have reference to the UIPageControl instance. Then you can basically manipulate the position of the pageControl. Refer to this code:

```
let pageControl = UIPageControl()
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
pageControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
pageControl.numberOfPages = 4
pageControl.center = self.view.center
self.view.addSubview(pageControl)

pageControl.layer.position.y = self.view.frame.height - 200; 
// 200 point from bottom of the screen
```

Answer (score 1):

If your current y position is :

`appearance.layer.position.y`

then to apply a modification relative to it do :

`appearance.layer.position.y = appearance.layer.position.y +/- yourOffset`

BUT you can't achieve that this way. 
More explications here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24933544/1585121
tl;dr `UIPageViewController` simplement his UIPageControl, and you can't mofidy its position

Comment: Please provide some comment with your downvote so I can improve my answer